# How can I extract a custom HTTP POST request header in JavaScript for it to be transmitted in another POST request?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to extract a custom HTTP **request** header from a `POST` request using Javascript for it to be used in a request later. The reason why this needs to be a `POST` request is that this custom header is only incorporated on the `POST` HTTP method, and not `GET` or other HTTP verbs.

Let's say the custom HTTP `POST` request header is `X-CUSTOM-TOKEN`. How can I read and extract the value of `X-CUSTOM-TOKEN` from `POST /` before submitting it alongside the following (HTTP Form):

```
history.pushState('', '', '/');
document.body.innerHTML='<html><body style="background-color:black;"><form id="foobar" action="https://localhost:4449/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="access" value="true" /><input type="submit" value="Submit request" /></form></body></html>';
document.getElementById('foobar').submit();
```

I know this use-case sounds dumb, but it's for educational purposes where I can better understand JavaScript pertaining to HTTP transmission.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Some headers are set to HttpOnly and are not available to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Correct, but this doesn't apply to this scenario. The `X-CUSTOM-TOKEN` HTTP header does not have the `httpOnly` flag set to `true`. Generally, this is used alongside Cookie HTTP headers as these values contain session info, amongst other info. In this case the `X-CUSTOM-TOKEN` is not a sensitive HTTP header in nature and so such protection mechanisms should not be considered in this context.

Comment: I'm understanding that you are using javascript to send post data!
In XML Request, you can get header data with method getAllResponseHeaders() or getResponseHeader(name)
[XML Request Javascript Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#methods)

Comment: Hi yes, I'm familiar with `getAllResponseHeaders()`, and `getResponseHeader(name)` , but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm wanting to extract a HTTP **request** header, and **not** a HTTP **response** header. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get the request headers since you have to add them to the request yourself and the browser adds it's own when the request is sent. You can have the server respond with the header if that's under your control.

Comment: If you find a solution, please post it here. I'd love to know

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If the request was constructed using the Fetch API, then you can [interrogate the request object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/headers) for its headers.

But if the request was constructed using XMLHTTPRequest, there does not appear to be any way to obtain the headers from the prepared-but-unsent request. Of course, if the code is yours, you should have access to the values when you configure the XHR, and so you can use that opportunity to store the data somewhere that it can be retrieved later.

You're out of luck if the XHR is constructed by third-party code that you cannot edit. In that case, you could use some kind of server-side proxy to echo the data back to you. That would not be unusual in an educational setting.